Mark text in html by complex regexps with markup save
Here is my input HTML:


<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>complete guide</p>
        <p>
            At the moment, we have no <span>questions</span> regarding the model and <b>logic</b> of the application, so there are no highlighted questions in the presentation. 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>



Here (https://regex101.com/r/ghp1UQ/1) is my regular expression:
complete(([^\s]*)\s){0,24}questions|questions(([^\s]*)\s){0,24}complete

and here is my desired output HTML:


<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p><mark>complete guide</mark></p>
        <p>
            <mark>At the moment, we have no</mark> <span><mark>questions</mark></span> regarding the model and <b>logic</b> of the application, so there are no highlighted questions in the presentation. 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>



Words inside a regex match must be marked, and the DOM tree must be valid.
How can this be done, for example, with jsoup?

Use on HTML parser, not regex (because HTML is not sufficiently regular for anything other than trivial cases). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/67392

As @Richard has said, you can't parse HTML with regex. In that sense, your question is a duplicate. And jsoup won't help either.

Does this answer your question? RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags
